# Cloud security risk assessment

Tags: cloud-storage

I would like to know if there is any risk of using unlimited Google Drive bought from ebay if we consider the following.

I know that the person who sold me that (administrator of the domain) can see all my data. Do you know if he can access them without me knowing it or he needs to reset my password?

Can I store my data safely there if they are encrypted via VeraCrypt with secure (very strong) password and then divided using WinRAR which is protected by WinRAR encryption with different strong password?

I know I could lose that account anytime and I am ready for that (I use it only as backup and everything I have here I also have somewhere else).

Is there any other risk excent losing that account and stealing my encrypted files?

Is it safe to me to use my phone number and email for that account (Google keep asking me to do so).

Comment: Think about it: Why would you buy "unlimited Google Drive" from Ebay instead of Google?

Comment: @e-sushi - I suspect its one of the free business accounts google used to offer (a couple of years back to entice users) which you know how to pay for. I suspect the OP has realised the original domain is associated with the account as you cannot remove them (from the old free ones). But, yes, I would never buy anything like this off of eBay.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if there is any risk of using unlimited Google
>   Drive bought from ebay if we consider the following.
>
> I know that the person who sold me that (administrator of the domain)
>   can see all my data. Do you know if he can access them without me
>   knowing it or he needs to reset my password?

Buying Google Drive off eBay is dangerous as it's against the Google T&C's and you may find the account gets shut down. Also if the account is still accessible by the owner (administrator of the domain?) then yes they can do anything they wish to it.

> Can I store my data safely there if they are encrypted via VeraCrypt
>   with secure (very strong) password and then divided using WinRAR which
>   is protected by WinRAR encryption with different strong password?

Encrypting the files before sending them up to the cloud would mean that anyone who accesses the files cannot access the content. You do not need to double encrypt anything (waste of time). Just make sure it's encrypted on your machine, and that you choose a strong key (password). VeraCrypt would be fine, and you could still WinRAR the volume.

> Is it safe to me to use my phone number and email for that account
>   (Google keep asking me to do so).

I think you would be wise just signing up to Google directly and not buying services like this off eBay. If you can't afford it then you need to find an alternative solution (unfortunately I believe its against the T&Cs here to recommend products directly)